# "Clear All" action doesn't trigger userNotificationCenter(.. didReceive response.. ) delegate method

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter, unnotificationrequest

I want to perform some calculations when the user dismisses a notification.
This works as expected when dismissing a single notification. But I can't get it to work when dismissing a stack of notifications with "Clear All".

---

For this purpose I created an `UNNotificationCategory` with option `.customDismissAction`,

```
extension UNNotificationCategory {
    static let CUSTOM_CATEGORY_IDENTIFIER: String = "CUSTOM_CATEGORY_IDENTIFIER"
    static let customCategory: UNNotificationCategory =
        .init(identifier: CUSTOM_CATEGORY_IDENTIFIER, actions: [], intentIdentifiers: [],
              options: .customDismissAction
        )
}
```

registered my category with `UNNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories()`

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    public func application(_: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions _: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) {
        // ...
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            .setNotificationCategories([UNNotificationCategory.customCategory])
        // ...
    }
}
```

and for each new `UNNotificationRequest` I set the `content.categoryIdentifier` accordingly.

```
    func notificationRequest(title: String, body: String) -> UNNotificationRequest {
        let identifier = UUID().uuidString
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: true)
        
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = title
        content.body = body
        content.categoryIdentifier = UNNotificationCategory.CUSTOM_CATEGORY_IDENTIFIER
        
        return UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    }
```

On dismissing a single notification everything works as expected.
The `userNotificationCenter(_: UNNotificationCenter, didReceive response: ..)` delegate method is called, the `response.actionIdentifier` is `UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier` as expected and my code is performed.

```
    public func userNotificationCenter(_: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                       didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                       withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        switch response.actionIdentifier {
        case UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier:
            print("handle dismiss notification")
            
        case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier:
            print("handle dismiss notification")
            
        case let identifier:
            print("didReceive notificationResponse with identifier: \(identifier)")
        }
        completionHandler()
    }
```

But when multiple stacked notifications are dismissed all at once via swipe, "Clear All" action or "X" button, the delegate isn't called even once.

[image]

Is there any way I can be notified in this case?
(doesn't matter if dismissing a stack of x notifications would trigger the delegate once or x times)